Worldpress child theme: function NOT overriding
This is my function in wordpress child theme, but not overriding my style.css:
function my_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_scripts', 202 );

What is my wrong?

You provided code to include script.js. Issue may be due to some issues regarding child theme implementation.
1 Check whether the child theme properly created and active.

Also check child theme is not broken will shown at Appearance > Themes

child-theme/style.css
/*
 Theme Name:   Your Child Theme Name
 Template:     parent-theme-directory
*/

2 If script.js is not including then try below code.
function my_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_scripts', 20 );

If still style.css not including?
Try this
<?php
function my_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_enqueue_styles');

